# Enable the context menu from a CheckBox in a Fragments ListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a `Fragment` in which I've embedded a `ListView` and some other `View`s. The `ListView` is using customized layout for its list items, see below.

Edit: This is what I'd like to achieve. From the docs:

> In some cases in which the contextual actions
>   provide common action items, you might want to add a checkbox or a
>   similar UI element that allows users to select items, because they
>   might not discover the long-click behavior. When a user selects the
>   checkbox, you can invoke the contextual action mode by setting the
>   respective list item to the checked state with setItemChecked().

CustomListViewItem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/tvNotesListAdapterTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/tvNotesListAdapterTimestamp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_notes"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:drawableEnd="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The purpose of the `CheckBox` is for the user to be able to invoke a [Contextual Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu). However, I do not seem to get it right. As the developer examples shows, I've successfully invoked the contextual menu when long-clicking the `ListView` items. This was done in the `Fragment` that hosted the `ListView`.

How and where do I do the same thing for the `CheckBox`es in the `ListView`? In the `ArrayAdapter`, or in the `Fragment`?

Below is the code for the custom `ArrayAdapter`.

CustomArrayAdapter.java:

```
public class NotesArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> {

    private ArrayList<Note> allNotes;

    public NotesArrayAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Note> allNotes) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.arrayadapter_notes, allNotes);
        this.allNotes = allNotes;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            //R.layout.arrayadapter_notes is my custom layout for my ListView items.
            row = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.arrayadapter_notes, null);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNotesListAdapterTitle);
        TextView tvTimeStamp = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNotesListAdapterTimestamp);

        String timeStamp = allNotes.get(position).getTimestamp();
        String note = allNotes.get(position).getNote();

        tvTitle.setText(note);
        tvTimeStamp.setText(timeStamp);

        return row;
    }

}
```

I have not found any working examples of what I've described above. Any help in this matter would be appreciated. In short, I'm unsure of where and how to invoke the context menu, when one or more `CheckBox`es are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by implementing a callback interface in my `ArrayAdapter` class like this

```
private NotesAdapterCallback callback;

public interface NotesAdapterCallback {
    public void checkBoxChecked();
}

public void setCallback(NotesAdapterCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        row = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.arrayadapter_notes, null);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNotesListAdapterTitle);
    TextView tvTimeStamp = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNotesListAdapterTimestamp);
    CheckBox cbNote = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cb_notes);

    String timeStamp = allNotes.get(position).getTimestamp();
    String note = allNotes.get(position).getNote();

    tvTitle.setText(note);
    tvTimeStamp.setText(timeStamp);

    cbNote.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    return row;

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.checkBoxChecked();
        }
    }
}
```

and implementing the interface in my `Fragment` like this

```
private ActionMode mActionMode;

@Override
public void checkBoxChecked() {
    if (mActionMode != null) {
        return;
    }else{
        mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
    }
}

private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
    // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false; // Return false if nothing is done
    }

    // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.context_delete:

                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            case R.id.context_move:

                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Called when the user exits the action mode
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
    }
};
```

Don't forget to set the callback on the `ArrayAdapter`

```
notesAdapter = new NotesArrayAdapter(getActivity(), allNotes);
lwNotes.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
notesAdapter.setCallback(this);
```